# Looking for something similar to ui:repeat to use in a JSP

Tags: java, jsp, jsf

I just want to iterate over a list, I don't want any html spitted out,
so datalist and c:ForEach are not an option.
The reason is, the mockup is already made and as rule we have to use 
`<ul>` and `<li>`, so I can't use anything creating a table.

I have investigated and ui:repeat would do the job, but it does not work in a JSP.

I wish there was something like in STRUTS logic:iterate because I only need to iterate
over a list.

Thanks for your help.

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what exactly you mean with "datalist", but [Tomahawk's `<t:dataList>`](http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk/tagdoc/t_dataList.html) does not emit any HTML by default if you omit the `layout` attribute, so it ought to work out for you.

```html
<ul>
    <t:dataList value="#{memberHandler.subTypes}" var="subType">
        <li><h:outputText value="#{subType.fullSubtypeDisplayName}"/></li>
    </t:dataList>
</ul>
```

By the way, setting `layout="unorderedList"` should render exactly the same `<ul><li>` as in the above example:

```html
<t:dataList value="#{memberHandler.subTypes}" var="subType" layout="unorderedList">
    <h:outputText value="#{subType.fullSubtypeDisplayName}"/>
</t:dataList>
```

When using JSTL `<c:forEach>` on a JSP template referring a managed bean value, you are dependent on the JSP version used and whether JSF has already autocreated the managed bean beforehand. When using Servlet 2.5/JSP 2.1, you should be able to use `#{}` in JSTL tags:

```html
<ul>
    <c:forEach value="#{memberHandler.subTypes}" var="subType">
        <li><h:outputText value="#{subType.fullSubtypeDisplayName}"/></li>
    </c:forEach>
</ul>
```

When using Servlet 2.4/JSP 2.0, you should stick using `${}` and use `<c:out>` instead of `<h:outputText>` and ensure that JSF has already autocreated the managed bean beforehand in the view template by `#{}` which triggers autocreating beans whereas `${}` doesn't.

```html
<h:someComponent value="#{memberHandler.someThing}" />
...
<ul>
    <c:forEach value="${memberHandler.subTypes}" var="subType">
        <li><c:out value="${subType.fullSubtypeDisplayName}"/></li>
    </c:forEach>
</ul>
```

Tomahawk's `<t:dataList>` would be a much better alternative here.

Comment: I tried the first example, It shows the bullet for the list but nothing comes out in the outputText, also, there are 2 items in the list and it shows only one bullet

Comment: the t:datalist without anything still creates an unorderedList

Comment: That's then just your misinterpretation/misconfiguration.

Comment: thank you I got it working. I have another quick question for you. It is possible to do something like <ntc:graphicImage value="#{imageName(43,13)}" />, I know in struts you can do it, but I have not seen it done in JSF!

Answer (score 2):

[`<c:forEach>`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/c/forEach.html) doesn't generate any HTML. It only iterates through a collection or array. It does exactly the same thing as `<struts:iterate>`, but in a standard way, and with the JSP EL.

```
<ul>
    <c:forEach var="item" items="${myListOfItems}">
        <li><c:out value="${item.label}"/></li>
    </c:forEach>
</ul>
```

Comment: maybe I remember incorrectly and the problem was, it may not work with h:outputText

Comment: @John: you are wrong. Perhaps you're confusing with flow problems of using JSTL tags within other JSF iteration components like `<h:dataTable>`.

Comment: I thought you looked for something to use in a JSP based application, not a "JSF using JSP" application. I don't know about JSF. Sorry.

Comment: It is a bit of mix app I am working (I did not write it, but I need to solve this problem). It is a jsf and uses a mixure of xhtml and jsp. The page in question is a JSP

Comment: @Balus, I was wrong a first, now I remember why I could not usec:forEach and c:out, they would not work with the jsf, I have the code in front me and nothing gets rendered: <ul>
  <c:forEach var="subType" items="${memberHandler.subTypes}">
    <li><c:out value="${subType.fullSubtypeDisplayName}"/></li>
  </c:forEach>
</ul>